# Facebook Messenger Bot, send Image Attachment

Tags: facebook, bots, messenger

I'm creating a Facebook bot that has images uploaded to it, and it responds with an image. Can I send the image in an attachment and delete it off my server or do I have to send a URL to the image and keep the image on my server?

Answer (score 4):

You can use their Upload API to upload your attachments to their servers.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "message":{
    "attachment":{
      "type":"image", 
      "payload":{
        "url":"http://www.messenger-rocks.com/image.jpg", 
        "is_reusable":true,
      }
    }
  }
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/message_attachments?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

The upload call will respond back an attachment_id which can be used to send the attachment to the user without uploading it again.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "recipient": {
    "id": "USER_ID"
  },
  "message": {
    "attachment": {
      "type": "image",
      "payload": {
        "attachment_id": "1745504518999123"
      }
    }
  }
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/me/messages?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    curl  \
  -F recipient='{"id":"USER_ID"}' \
  -F message='{"attachment":{"type":"image", "payload":{}}}' \
  -F filedata=@/tmp/testpng.png \
  "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

Here you can find an official example on how to atach a jpg or a png.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference#examples

Comment: Do you know how to do it through python and specially when file is a PIL image which I can not save in the server?

Comment: Don´t know, try to look for a Python library the wraps FB APIs. What is a PIL image?

Comment: Here's how to do it in python using requests and additional requests_toolbelt library.   https://gist.github.com/fatfingers/d7c090068a68b8b7238bd85374b6e34c

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, but still found no answer.

For now, the only way to send images with Facebook bot, is "image_url" with your's image url.

Comment: Yeah, that's what the API says :( My temporary solution will be to prompt the user to download the image within n hours before a cron job wipes it off the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can send attachments via the Facebook Messenger API by POSTing them directly (without using the `payload.url` option) with a **multipart request**. Here it is with PHP & [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#multipart) (though any good HTTP Request package should do, regardless of the scripting language):

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client();
$graphRequest = $client->request('POST', 'https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/me/messages', [
    'query' => [
        'access_token' => $facebookInfo['pageAccessToken']
    ],
    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name' => 'messaging_type',
            'contents' => 'RESPONSE',
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'recipient',
            'contents' => json_encode(['id' => $yourRecipientPSID]),
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'message',
            'contents' => json_encode(['attachment' => ['type' => 'file', 'payload' => []]]),
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'filedata',
            'contents' => fopen($yourFilePath, 'r'),
            'filename' => $yourFileName,
        ],
    ],
]);
```

Note that the `attachments.payload` parameter is set, but `null`. The Graph API returns a 400 response if `payload` is not set.